# htaccess partial filename suffix match

Tags: .htaccess

As part of a site migration, I have a bunch of old files that I want to redirect to a new site.

The old files all end with `_reviews.html`, but the new destination is on a different server, without the "`_reviews`" part of the name, but still ending in `.html`.

For example:

Old:

```
www.a.com/my_product1_reviews.html
```

New:

```
www.b.com/my_product1.html
```

I have a few hundred like this so I didn't really want to do them one at a time, but I can't seem to get the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)_reviews.html$ http://www.b.com/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't work. It is not redirecting at all.

Comment: Try it now, with the RewriteBase.  You have this in an .htaccess file at your public root folder, right?  And mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: Still didn't work. I do use the rewrite engine already in that htaccess file for other things. I also tested an exact Redirect 301 rule and that worked, so the htacess file is being ready and used.