# Redirect folder and partial filename

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've changed an entire folder of PHP files to a new folder with a more friendly name along with 83 files. Most incoming URIs have named anchors '#'.

I need to redirect links for the old folder/filename, including named anchors, to the folder/filename, retaining whatever part of the URI that comes after the changed portion.

I can do individual files, using individual lines of Redirect, but wonder if there is some way to do it globally.

Change:
mysite.com/folder1/filename1-(other stuff, including named anchors)

to:
mysite.com/folder2/filename2-(other stuff, including named anchors)

I've spent a couple hours looking in the archives, and online searches for Rewrite and Redirect, but nothing addresses redirecting partial file names.

I need some help writing either a RewriteCond/Rule or a Redirect. Thanks in advance for any help offered.

(edit) I decided to simply redirect all requests for any page in /folder1/ to the main index page for /folder2/, using Redirectmatch.

RedirectMatch ^/folder1/filename1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/index.php

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so post it.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know anything about regular expressions, or whatever is used to craft a Rewrite to do what I need.

Comment: Is Apache the web server? If so, do you have access to a .htaccess file? If you're redirecting # parameters, then you do that with a server script like PHP, Perl, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is an Apache server. Yes, I have access to the htaccess file. I have lots and lots of individual redirects. I would like to do some of them globally.

Comment: Kind of like this message from May 2013, but I need to redirect files with the same prefix, instead of the same suffix. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859325/htacess-partial-filename-suffix-match>

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
Change: mysite.com/folder1/filename1.php?a=1&b=2#3
to:     mysite.com/folder2/filename2.php?a=1&b=2#3
```

Inside the .htaccess file in the directory where folder2 resides, assuming web root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)1-(\d+).php$ folder2/$12-$2.php [QSA,R=301,NC,L]
```

This matches folder1 followed by a string, digit 1, dash, and one or more digits. Then redirects that to folder2 followed by the same string, digit 2, dash, and the same one or more digits captured in the regex.

The query string and hash parameters are transferred with the QSA flag.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, if there is a way to rewrite the prefix portion of the file name. The "filename1" vs. "filename2" is not the complete file name, so I need something that rewrites just a portion of the file name. I think I see that it would have to be with a regular expression, but such a thing is way beyond me.

Comment: folder1 does not exist. I already renamed and moved the 83+ files to folder2 about three months ago. I just discovered some old forum links to folder1, and want to globally redirect them to folder2. If I put your solution in my root htaccess, is it before or after the many, many redirects?

Comment: Or would it better to recreate folder1 with just a simple htaccess, then have only this in the htaccess?

Comment: No, I updated the response to use in the root directory.

Comment: Thank you, but it's the other way round. The file names begin differently but end the same, as in filename1-24.php#anchor1 vs. filename2-24.php#anchor1. Does the RewriteRule go after the list of Redirects?

Comment: Response updated. See if the necessary connection between the old files and the new files is captured there.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. And I'm done. Thank you for taking the time to try this, but I'll just do a simple 301 Redirect for the entire folder1, and redirect it to the top level index page of folder2. One line in my htaccess, and no regular expressions. Which is probably what I should have done in the first place, and not try to redirect individual pages. Rewriting the folders worked, but trying to rewrite the file names is too complex for me.

Comment: This is what works to redirect any and all requests for any file in /folder1/ to the main index page for /folder2/. RedirectMatch ^/folder1/filename1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/index.php